# EWS managed API for Windows Phone8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, exchangewebservices

I wanted to access emails from Exchange server (through EWS) using EWS Managed API on WindowsPhone8 app .But EWS Managed API is not compatible with WindowsPhone8 app . So only choices left is either to create Webservice of my own which can access emails using EWS managed API and then call the custom created service from the windows Phone app or I have to invoke the EWS url from windows phone app directly by using httpclient and constructing soap service request and parsing the results based on the response. Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: If you only want to access Office 365 you can use its [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776319%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) with OAuth authentication. That would be simpler than building your own SOAP communications, and my guess is that other people are working on it also.

Comment: The App should access at least exchange 2010 and 2013 , so is there no other better way ?